# How to convert nest list into a multiple records dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

Given a nested list such as:

```
        [{'status': 200,
          'data': {'count': 1,
           'next': None,
           'previous': None,
           'results': [{'name': 'ABC',
             'app_id': '10000001',
             'is_flag': None,
             'start_date': '2005-01-22'}]}},
          {'status': 200,
           'data': {'count': 1,
           'next': None,
           'previous': None,
           'results': [{'name': 'ABC',
             'app_id': '10000002',
             'is_flag': pass,
             'start_date': '2005-01-22'}]}},
          {'status': 200,
           'data': {'count': 1,
           'next': None,
           'previous': None,
           'results': [{'name': 'ABC',
             'app_id': '10000003',
             'is_flag': None,
             'start_date': '2005-01-22'}]}}]
```

If I want to get and store into a dataframe like this:

| app_id | is_flag |
| --- | --- |
| 10000001 | None |
| 10000002 | pass |
| 10000003 | None |

I tried the following:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(result)
temp.head()
```

But the temp is not giving me **three individual records in the dataframe** but all in one record, any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "count": 1,
        "next": None,
        "previous": None,
        "results": [
            {
                "name": "ABC",
                "app_id": "10000001",
                "is_flag": None,
                "start_date": "2005-01-22",
            }
        ],
    },
},
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "count": 1,
        "next": None,
        "previous": None,
        "results": [
            {
                "name": "ABC",
                "app_id": "10000002",
                "is_flag": "pass",
                "start_date": "2005-01-22",
            }
        ],
    },
},
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "count": 1,
        "next": None,
        "previous": None,
        "results": [
            {
                "name": "ABC",
                "app_id": "10000003",
                "is_flag": None,
                "start_date": "2005-01-22",
            }
        ],
    },
},
```

]

```
df = pd.DataFrame([obj['data']['results'][0] for obj in data])
```

If you don't want to have the `name` column in your final dataframe, just drop it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data['results'][0] for data in result]).drop(['name'], axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you! But the point is the dict im getting don't have a comma to split each bracket. (pls referring to the above sample). Hence the solution didn't work here.

Comment: Please provide either a valid python dictionary or a json object you are trying to convert into a dataframe.

Comment: Here you go, much appreciate your time. result =  [{'count': 1, 'next': None, 'previous': None, 'results': [{'name': 'ABC', 'app_id': '10000001', 'is_flag': None}]}
           {'count': 1, 'next': None, 'previous': None, 'results': [{'name': 'ABC', 'app_id': '10000002', 'is_flag': None}]}
           {'count': 1, 'next': None, 'previous': None, 'results': [{'name': 'ABC', 'app_id': '10000003', 'is_flag': None}]}]

Comment: the json dict object I had are multiple dictionaries that are not separated by commas which is not a list of dictionaries you listed, hence I can not use the query you provided.

Comment: The code you provided isn't a valid python code nor is it a valid json object. Can you please explain how is this data created/loaded?

Comment: thank you for your input. I changed it to a nested list instead of the dict. (the list obj is showing above)

Comment: Do you receive this data or do you generate it? It still contains errors. There are no commas after the `app_id` elements, there's an extra `]` bracket in the end, and `is_flag` is equal to `pass` which is not a string or a python object.

Comment: Sry about the confusion, I updated the data. It's pull thru the API calls, and I had to remove the sensitive data to replace with the dummy ones. The is_flag is showing as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235546/discussion-between-gfchqz-and-george).

Comment: I updated the code based on the info you provided with a single assumption that `pass` values might be converted to strings.

Comment: thank you for your input, it didn't work for me. But I posted my solution down below, if you want to take a look.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that. Could you please provide your `data` variable value? It seems that you modified it in a way supported by python. Unfortunately, your question still doesn't contain a valid python list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by convert list of nested dictionary into Pandas dataframe, shown below:

```
 # rows list initialization
    rows=[]
    #appending rows
    for data in data:
        data_row = data['data']['results']
        for row in data_row:
            rows.append(row)

#using dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```